How to "delete until the second occurence of )"?
In the following line
gg <- ggplot(dt.llh, aes(x = entropy.rel, group = as.factor(cell.type))) +

how to delete the following portion of the code with the least key strokes?

, group = as.factor(cell.type)

I typically go to end of entropy.rel manually, and then use dt)x, but is there somehow a way of saying "delete until the second occurence of )"?

"with the least key strokes?" - this reads like a vimgolf question and the community seems to dislike them.

Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help your further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the answer using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

d2f)

d: delete
2: Till the second occurrence of the delimiter character
f: Go forward and include the delimiter character
): The delimiter character is )

NB: If you want to preserve the second ), replace f by t.

Well, or 2t) to match OP’s “til”

When deleting function calls with balanced parentheses, use %:
d%

This will accomplish what you like without counting. Note that % seeks forward to a bracket and then jumps to its match, so includes the , group = bit, too.

If you don't mind a plugin-based solution, you can use nvim-treesitter-textobjects to add a parameter textobject.
Minimal configuration would be:
require("nvim-treesitter.configs").setup({
  ensure_installed = { "r" },
  textobjects = {
    select = {
      enable = true,
      keymaps = {
        ["ia"] = "@parameter.outer",
        ["aa"] = "@parameter.outer",
      },
    },
  },
})

After which you can delete the argument (from anywhere on it) with daa.

I would do:
d])

The ]) moves to the matching parenthesis such that you don't have to count how many you have to skip.
In  particular this approach will also work in the following case:
gg <- ggplot(dt.llh, aes(x = entropy.rel, group = as.factor(cell.type) + (foo * (bar - x))) +

